# Logging XML from external web service

Tags: .net, vb.net, webservice-client

I have been provided an WSDL file for a VB 2005 .NET application and I generated a .vb file using the wsdl command using Visual Studio Command Prompt.  I can connect to this web service and send it data using a complex type provided by the WSDL through several methods.  Any of the methods that return a int or string type work fine.

Any of the methods that return a complex type is returning XML errors when the serialization occurs.  I can't figure out how to actually see the XML that the web service is returning since it will not let me step through.

System.InvalidOperationException = {"There is an error in XML document (10, 53)."}

This is the call:

```
    '''<remarks/>
<System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("http://www.sample.com/RetrieveUsersStatuses", RequestNamespace:="http://www.sample.com", ResponseNamespace:="http://www.sample.com")>  _
Public Function RetrieveUsersStatus(ByVal authToken As String, ByVal ids() As String) As <System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("statuses")> Userstatus()
    Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("RetrieveUsersStatus", New Object() {authToken, ids})
    Return CType(results(0),Userstatus())
End Function
```

EDIT: I can step further into the project after unchecking 'Enable Just My Code' where leads me to this error

```
Cannot assign object of type System.Xml.XmlNode[] to an object of type ...
```

It seems that a lot of people are having a similar problem when they try to consume a PHP WSDL into a webservice using .NET.

Comment: Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com).

Comment: Thanks!  I can see the response but I don't see what the error is.  I might end having to capture the XML in .net and try to manually work with it.

Comment: I expect you're seeing one of the issues with RPC-style services. You may need to post parts of the WSDL, specifically the parts that have to do with this particular operation that's failing.

Comment: @John:  I suspect this is the problem too after doing further digging.  Unfortunately I can't post a whole lot but it does look to be RPC Encoded.

Comment: I believe that PHP _can_ do "document" style services, but that some people just think RPC is the way to go. It's not. It doesn't comply with [WS-I BP-1.1](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.0-2004-04-16.html).